# Django/mod_wsgi/Apache - mod_wsgi is not using the Python version it was compiled for - "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'math' "

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm attempting to deploy a Django application with Apache2 and mod_wsgi on a Ubuntu 16.04.6 server, but I'm struggling with getting mod_wsgi to use the correct python version.

I installed mod_wsgi from source, and [configured it](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html#configuring-the-source-code) to compile against the system python3, specifically python3.7.8

My Virtual environment for the Django app is also running python3.7.8.

My VirtualHost config file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName kumberas.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.com

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/dan/app/kumberas/kumberas/main/wsgi.py
        Alias /static/ /home/dan/app/kumberas/kumberas/static/

        <Directory /home/dan/app/kumberas/kumberas/static>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/dan/app/kumberas/venv>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/dan/app/kumberas/kumberas/main>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
            </Files>
        </Directory>

        <Location />
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Restricted Content"
            AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
            Require user kr
            AuthBasicProvider file
        </Location>

        WSGIDaemonProcess kumberas \
            python-home=/home/dan/app/kumberas/venv \
            python-path=/home/dan/app/kumberas
        WSGIProcessGroup kumberas

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

And when I try to access the site, I get a 500 Error and the following in my Apache error log.

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 21635] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:58603] mod_wsgi (pid=21635): Failed to exec Python script file '/home/dan/app/kumberas/kumberas/main/wsgi.py'.
[wsgi:error] [pid 21635] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:58603] mod_wsgi (pid=21635): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/dan/app/kumberas/kumberas/main/wsgi.py'.
[wsgi:error] [pid 21635] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:58603] Traceback (most recent call last):
[wsgi:error] [pid 21635] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:58603]   File "/home/dan/app/kumberas/kumberas/main/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[wsgi:error] [pid 21635] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:58603]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[wsgi:error] [pid 21635] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:58603]   File "/home/dan/app/kumberas/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[wsgi:error] [pid 21635] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:58603]     from django.utils.version import get_version
[wsgi:error] [pid 21635] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:58603]   File "/home/dan/app/kumberas/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 1, in <module>
[wsgi:error] [pid 21635] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:58603]     import datetime
[wsgi:error] [pid 21635] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:58603]   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/datetime.py", line 8, in <module>
[wsgi:error] [pid 21635] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:58603]     import math as _math
[wsgi:error] [pid 21635] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:58603] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'math'
```

I did a bit of digging and found this [`wsgi.py`](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use) file in the mod_wsgi documentation for checking the python version that mod_wsgi is using, and get the following output when I visit the site:

```
sys.version = '3.7.2 (default, Jan 23 2020, 09:44:10) \n[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]'
sys.prefix = '/home/dan/app/kumberas/venv'
```

I assume the mismatching python version `3.7.8 != 3.7.2` is the issue here, but as far as I'm aware there isn't a python3.7.2 installation on the server, and I've reinstalled mod_wsgi several times making certain that I configure it to use 3.7.8.

I've also confirmed that while in the virtual environment I'm, a) able to run the Django application with `manage.py runserver`, and b) can run `get_wsgi_application()` manually in the Django shell.

Does anyone have any knowledge on whether this version mismatch is the issue, and how it could be resolved?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue (using Bottle rather than Django). I've added a bounty to try and attract some answers.

Comment: Have you used venv or virtualenv to creating your environment?

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but have you tried moving "WSGIScriptAlias" after "WSGIProcessGroup". I'm not sure order is important in Apache config files, but that's something I would try. I would also check what the output of os.path.dirname(sys.executable) is to find out which Python executable is being used. Ultimately, I would try adding "site-packages" to your python-path.

Comment: `locate mod_wsgi.so`. `ldd /path/to/mod_wsgi.so|grep libpy` - does that give any indication about the python version that mod_wsgi was built with?

Comment: *"I'm just guessing here, "* - yep, indeed. Scope matters, order within a scope does not.

Answer (score 0):

If virtualenv or virtualenvwrapper have been used to create environment then you need to call activation script in wsgi.py:

```py
python_home = '/home/dan/app/kumberas/venv'

activate_this = python_home + '/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have a version mismatch. Some linux is still using python 2.7 as the default.

Also check if the system has more than one version of python using `locate python` and/or `locate python3`

If it's an issue on `modwsgi`, it might be easier for you to build mod_wsgi from source following link https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html