# Module wsgi error when deploying Django app on apache

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I had developped an application using Django (DRF). And I try to deploy it on a server. After following some tutorials on Internet, I got this error :

```
mod_wsgi (pid=27182): Failed to exec Python script file '/my/django/project/path/myProjectName/wsgi.py'.
 mod_wsgi (pid=27182): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/my/django/project/path/myProjectName/wsgi.py'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/my/django/project/path/myProjectName/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
   File "/my/django/project/path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
     from django.utils.version import get_version
   File "/my/django/project/path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 1, in <module>
     import datetime
   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/datetime.py", line 12, in <module>
     import math as _math
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'math'
```

I had checked on some forums but I didn't find a solution to solve my problem. It seems that the problem comes from wsgi module, which is already installed when I was configure the server using this command:
`sudo apt install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`

This is my V-host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
     
 
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 
        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, no
        ErrorLog /my-django/project/path/error.log
        CustomLog /my-django/project/path/access.log combined
 
 
        ServerName my-domaine.com
        ServerAlias www.my-domaine.com
        DocumentRoot /my-django/project/path
        Alias /static /my-django/project/path/static
 
 
        <Directory /my-django/project/path/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
 
    Alias /media /my-django/project/path/media
        <Directory /my-django/project/path/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
 
    <Directory /my-django/project/path/myProject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
        </Files>
        </Directory>
 
    WSGIScriptAlias / /my-django/project/path/myProject/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/my-django/project/path python-home=/my-django/project/path/venv
    WSGIProcessGroup django_app
</VirtualHost>
```

What can I do to solve this problem ?

**Edit**

When I run python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 on my server

```
  The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/my-django-project-path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/my-django-project-path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 144, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/my-django-project-path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/runserver.py", line 27, in get_handler
    handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/my-django-project-path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 70, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "/my-django-project-path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 48, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'myDjangoProject.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
```

Comment: This is really strange. `math` is a standard module that comes with Python and so should automatically be available.

Comment: Not specifically about your problem, but it looks like you are using the system python. This is considered a bad practice and I suggest that you create a virtual environment using `venv`, `pipenv`, `poetry` or a similar tool for your django app.

Comment: I'm working in a virtual env :
- Install : sudo apt install python3-venv
- Create venv : python -m venv venv-name
- Activate : source /path/to/venv/bin/activate

Comment: A similar problem is reported here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63398489/django-mod-wsgi-apache-mod-wsgi-is-not-using-the-python-version-it-was-compile][1]

 Try to have a look, probably relevant to the different versions of Python. (Remember that there are a lot of Python versions and you should check if the server is using the exact version you are supposed to run)

Comment: @youstra I saw `/usr/lib/python3.9/datetime.py` in the error which looks like the system installation of python. But I might be thinking of this incorrectly since a virtual environment just provides symbolic links to python executables. The built in libraries might still be in `/usr/lib`, which I wasn't expecting and really don't know for sure how venv manages them.